# How to inline assembly into file scope passing Rust-defined constants?

Tags: rust, embedded, bare-metal

I need the same behavior as the `global_asm!` macro, but passing constants defined in my Rust code. The obvious choice would be to use a (private) naked function that contains inline `asm!` instruction, but I don't see any way to prevent such a function from being removed by linker as unused. Can you suggest a proper way of doing that?

Comment: Did you try the [`#[used]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/abi.html#the-used-attribute) attribute?

Comment: AFAIK this attribute can be applied to static variables only.